# Error compiling a C# Windows Forms applicaiton with mono on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, mono, compiler-errors, debian, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile my C# application to the Raspberry Pi (running Debian).

I have successfully installed mono on the Pi, compiled, and run a basic hello world application. I am now running the following command ([from here](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms_Getting_Started_Guide)) to try and compile my windows forms application:

```
`dmcs -pkg:dotnet Login.cs /r:system.Windows.Forms /r:System.Drawing`
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error CS006; Metadata file 'cscompmgd.dll' could not be found Compilation failed: 1 error(s)
```

So my questions are:

1) Could this because I am trying to reference

> Using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

2) If the answer to 1 is no, what else could cause that error?

3) Related question: My application has a few different forms, will compiling this Login.cs file be enough to run the whole application, or should I; compile them all at once, or compile program.cs?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, the error you are getting, is because of the library you are trying to reference.  You will have to reference a library that is supported by Mono which means a library compiled by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file I related to the compiler. This might help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=914626. As for MySQL client, you might need more libraries, I would recommend compiling your app on a separate computer (with more harddisk and memory a transferring your binary to the raspberry Pi (the extra step might make builds a little trickier but the extra space and power might make a full build envrionment easier)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it won't let me copy files from the directory specified in that article. It only lets me install / uninstall. As for compiling on another system, I have compiled it in windows 7, and copied across the exe, but it doesnt start or do anything

Comment: @Wayneio - If its not starting it means your missing a required reference and is actually failing to even initialize far enough to give you an error.